# Can I ask a question about writing an 'about me' page of my blog as it will be read by my readers?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am working on my blog. In the about me page i want to write my story. I suffered from depression and the blog is eventual output of that.

I want to ask if that is a good way to communicate with your potential readers. As they will think it is written by a ex-depressed guy.

My blog is NOT about depression.

Comment: Probably primarily opinion based, but you could try it out in the [sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/3201#3201) and get some feedback.