# Didn't Understand the reason behind Answer Delete

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

[This Was my answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/how-to-stop-classmate-from-bullying-me/18070#18070) , Okay Everyone said and presented their views , I did that too ,Even my thing really worked for me as well as the problem was also faced by me so I just wrote what I did . Why would anyone have any objection in it ? I didn't advice him to cast a nuclear war with him !

I know I don't contribute much to this community but when I do I don't understand why Downvotes ,deletion (I already read the policy and all and have a tour completion badge too ,so please don't just give me a link and cruelly say read and examine )

Ps: Please be kind this maybe last of me in this site.

Note: It may take me a while for responding due to Internet Issues so please if you wish to help have patience

Answer (score 5):

I was one of the people who put your answer in the review queue. Please don't get me wrong: **your answer is full of valuable advice and knowledge about how to deal with bullying**. The problem is that, as is, this is not an IPS answer.
I'm gonna explain below what IPS answers should look like, but first, I would like to **apologize to you**: when I review answers and cast for deletion, I normally put a comment below to explain the author of the answer **why their answer is not fully addressing OP's issue** and how they could edit their answer to make it on topic. I had some connection problems yesterday and had to rerun many of the commands I did to moderate the site. My comment under your answer might have get lost in those timeout requests. Now I know that IPS is a difficult Stack to get used to, because of the very nature of its topic: interpersonal skills.

### What makes an answer on-topic

You mentioned you don't wanna get redirected to another link, so I'm gonna cherry-pick the gist points. On IPS, we expect answers either to:

- **[Directly address](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) OP's issue**. Such an answer could look like:

> Regarding problem *X*, I suggest you take measures *Y*. I think this could work in your situation because *Z*.

*Z* could be that the answerer has already tried that in similar situations. In that case, they should tell how it went, so OP has an idea of what to expect. It could also be an explanation of why it should work. The answerer *can* (and is actually welcome to) add personal information, like you have in your answer, as further evidence that what they're suggesting might work in such situation. The problem here is that your answer has *Z*, but not *Y*.

Another possible kind of answers would be:

- **[Frame challenging](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-not-answering-a-question-and-posting-a-frame-chal) OP's question**. I would like to point out the difficulty of such approach. By frame-challenging the question, the answerer wants to tell OP that what they're trying to achieve is likely not a good idea. Now of course, such answers must explain why OP shouldn't try to do it.

It could be phrased as:

> Your goal of trying to do *X* is, in my opinion, not a good idea. Here's why: *Z*.

Again, the *Z* part is very important here, because otherwise it does not help OP to rethink about their situation.
In the context of frame-challenge answers, the answerer can still suggest what OP should do regarding their issue and then explain why they shouldn't try to achieve their goal. This is recommended and appreciated, but is not mandatory. Only *Z* is mandatory here.

### What you could do with your answer

When we flag an answer and/or cast [delete votes](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), it's because it does not (fully) meet either one of the two aforementioned forms. But it's not a final decision! Your answer (as it belongs to the first category) just needs a *Y*. You might want to suggest to OP what they should do regarding their bullying, and why you think that'd work. **This is all it needs**: the personal experience you shared enforces your legitimacy to advise OP.

This is why we normally comment under answers that does not fully meet the site requirements, to let the answerer edit their contribution and try to make it on-topic. Your answer is deleted now, but it can come back! Once you've edited it, you can cast a undelete vote, which puts it in a review queue, where other IPS users will have the chance to cast the two other votes needed to reopen your answer.

### Further help

Again, I'm sorry this comment got lost. We really want our new users to have a pleasant experience here, which is why we make ourselves available to help you. If you ever have difficulties to edit content, you can require help by either pinging other users or [mods](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators), or by stopping by in our [official chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence), where there's an (almost) constant on- and off-discussion. Same goes for questions, except that we have a dedicated place where people (no matter how much rep they have) who are unsure that their question would be a good fit for this stack can post and require the help of other users to phrase it. It's called the Sandbox, and it's [right here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions?cb=1).

Have a nice time on IPS!

Comment: Sorry for the delay , b/w I think miss you didn't read my answer properly there was Y no Z and considering the points of my answer I don't really think there's need for Z as they are all adapted from great books and experiences of hon'ble people(80/20 principle and all )

Comment: [This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46676497#46676497) is something you should read (maybe) and I wont be ever selecting your answer a appropriate one (maybe we have understanding issues) anyway .