# What is the Sandbox? How do I use it?

Tags: discussion, faq, sandbox

- Where is the sandbox?
- Why should I use the sandbox?
- How does the sandbox work?
- How should I format my sandbox post?

Answer (score 5):

## Where is the Sandbox?

The sandbox is currently located at [this meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).

## Why should I use the Sandbox?

Sometimes writing a clear and answerable question on the first try can be difficult. There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the sandbox first. Posting to the sandbox allows the community to give you feedback on whether it is unclear or off-topic before it's already on the main site. This is especially helpful if significant edits are needed, so that you can freely edit without worrying about invalidating early answers.

## How does the Sandbox work?

There are more details in [the meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), but the short version is:

1. You have a question you're thinking of asking, but aren't sure if it's a good fit for the site. Maybe you don't know if it's quite on-topic, or what details you should include.
2. You post an answer to the sandbox containing your draft of the question.
3. After you post there, people will give suggestions to improve it and point out potential issues. (New sandbox answers are posted to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) automatically to increase visibility.)
4. You edit your post in response to the suggestions.
5. When users think your post is good, they will upvote it in the sandbox. You should wait until a sufficient number of people seem to support your proposed question before posting it on the main site.
6. If it's ready, post your question on the main site! Then, edit your sandbox post so that it only contains the title, linked to the main site URL, and add the link to the list of graduated questions.
7. Or, if you decide not to post it, edit your sandbox post so that it only contains "Not Posted: " and the title.
8. Finally, delete your sandbox post, so that it is easier to find posts that are still being worked on.

## How should I format my sandbox post?

Posts aren't required to follow a specific format, but some general guidance makes it easier to use the Sandbox. In general, questions should include the title, tags, and body. You can also include sandbox notes for additional information or questions about your post. Here's an example template:

```
# My Question Title

Tags: [tag:some-tag] [tag:another-tag]

Write the body of question here, as you intend to post it on main.

---

## Sandbox Questions

This section can be used to add some notes or questions for reviewers, such as specific
points that you'd like to get feedback on.
```