# How to fix? — How do I tactfully stop family, who runs a competitor store, from spying on our business? —

Tags: discussion

I'm so so sorry for badly writing [How do I tactfully stop family, who runs a competitor store, from spying on our business?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/22443/19744)! Please don't suspend me!

How can I rewrite my question to make it on-topic? Thx!!!

Comment: BOOH! I'm the big bad mod that suspends everyone... but you don't have to be afraid ;) Unless people write *loads* of bad questions and never improve (so new questions are consistently just as bad as old ones, even after the old ones have received much guidance for improving)... we don't suspend people for writing one question that's not on-topic ;)

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing to worry about. Sometimes one struggles to make a question on topic. It happens to everyone! Y**ou won't get suspended for a single off topic question**, automatic suspensions are issued when a user posts several posts that do not respect the site requirements in a relatively short amount of time.

If you're new to the site or would like to post a question but are not sure how to phrase it to make it on topic, I suggest you **post it in [the Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) first**. This is a dedicated place where users can help you find the best way to phrase your question. It's helped a significant number of users in writing on topic questions so far :) And when the question is ready, you then may take it to the main site.

What is unfortunate in your situation is that people voted to close your question but didn't leave a comment explaining what was wrong. My guess is that the goal you want to achieve seems to be more about legal issues than interpersonal skills. However, that does not mean we couldn't make it on topic! If it would still suit your needs, maybe you could rephrase it into something along the lines of "how do we communicate to my uncle that we do not appreciate his copycat patterns and that he's hurting my parents' business?". If you choose to go for such a question, don't forget to explain what you have tried so far and what was the outcome (did you talk to him about it? What did you tell him? How did he react?). When your question is closed and think we could find a better phrasing that could suit the site's requirements, d**on't hesitate to drop by [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence)** and ask users if they could help you rephrase it, or if someone left a comment explaining what's wrong, **ask them to tell you more about how to improve it** (if it's possible to make it on topic).

### Parting notes

I believe your question may be edited a little to focus more on how to communicate to your uncle that he's hurting your parents' business. However, please remember that we can't force anyone to stop anything, so such question would likely focus on how to communicate your issues to your uncle, not how to ask him to stop. When you're unsure or if your question gets close votes, don't hesitate to drop by chat and ask for help or ask people who left a comment to tell you more about what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind editing the question pls? "I believe your question may be edited a little to focus more on how to communicate to your uncle that he's hurting your parents' business." - Not sure what your words you had in mind?

Comment: @PamelaLee Sorry about the late answer. Well, if that would still suit your needs, maybe you could ask "how to communicate to my uncle that his actions are hurting my parents' business" instead?