# How to improve on off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, questions

My account has been locked due to bad questions, partly they were off-topic.

Is there really a chance to improve from there?

For example, this question has been off-topic. I.e. my interpersonal skills seem to be not the topic of the question. So is the way to bend the topic to something related but different if I do not want to accept that I've been locked out here?

[How to act more politely despite of beng mixed up?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/how-to-act-more-politely-despite-of-beng-mixed-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is the way to bend the topic to something related but different if I do not want to accept that I've been locked out here?

No. Editing your posts to ask completely different new questions, just because the question ban doesn't allow you to ask them 'the normal way', is never acceptable. From the [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include: [...] To clarify the meaning of the post (*without changing that meaning*)

Edits are not supposed to be used to change the meaning of a post. Editing it into an entirely new question would change the meaning of a post, so it's not okay to do so. Especially not in an attempt to circumvent system restrictions.

> Is there really a chance to improve from there?

Looking at all of your questions, including the deleted ones, I don't see any that you could improve. I do see that [you got a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/369802) before asking 'Are polyamoric families real?'. At that point, you should've already stepped back and thought about whether this was really something that belonged on a site about Interpersonal Skills (which are the behaviors people use to interact with others and achieve certain goals).

As the [guidance you've been linked to](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) in the automatic message telling you about your question ban states:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. Your ban is immediately reinstated once that question is posted, but a single question could be enough to lift you out of the block.

At this point, all you can do is wait until you can ask that question. You'd better make sure that question is a good one, one that is on-topic for this site and includes sufficient details. When that time comes around, consider using the [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/1599) on meta first.

Comment: thank you for the explanations.